# api call returns value later and the method that calls the api doesnt get the value from the api in Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

i have a method findFdsUserSearchParams that calls a service getContactSearchParams api but before this returns a value the remaining statemnents executes and  (d) is undefined and then i see the value is returned in service but it doesnt come back to this method though i have a subscribe here

this.contactFdsService.getContactSearchParams(this.cdsid).subscribe((d) =>

How do i make this wait for the getContactSearchParams to get the value and then go to execute the next line which is
if (d) {
}
so d will get a value.

```
  findFdsUserSearchParams(): any {
    if (this.cdsid.length > 1) {
      this.contactFdsService.getContactSearchParams(this.cdsid).subscribe((d) => {
       
        if (d) {
       
          this.fdsSearchData = d;    
         
          if (d.length > 0) {
            this.showfdsSearchParam = true;
          } else {
            this.showfdsSearchParam = false;
          }
        } else {
          this.fdsSearchData = d;
        
          this.showfdsSearchParam = true;
        }
 });
    }
  }
```

This is the service with api call

```
 getContactSearchParams(cdsid: string): Observable<any> {
   
    const body = JSON.stringify({ site: 'ras-admin', cdsid: cdsid, CDSIDBeginsWith: cdsid, searchType: "get-fds-user-search" });

  
    const endpoint = environment.endpointContacts;
    const endpointFds = environment.endpointContactsFds + "/find-users/execute/0";
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "x-app-validate": environment.fdsAppValidateHeader,
        "No-Auth": "True",
      }),
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(endpoint, body).pipe(
      switchMap((fdsDataFromSql) => {
       
        if (fdsDataFromSql == null || (Array.isArray(fdsDataFromSql) && fdsDataFromSql[0].fdsContact.length == 0)) {
          

          const bodyFirstName = JSON.stringify({ cdsid: cdsid, FirstNameContains: cdsid, searchType: "get-fds-user-search" });

          this.http.post<any>(endpointFds, body, httpOptions).subscribe((d) => {
            this.cdsid = d.results;
            this.cdsval = this.cdsid.concat(this.firstNameval);
           
          });
          this.http.post<any>(endpointFds, bodyFirstName, httpOptions).subscribe((d) => {
            this.firstNameval = d.results;
            this.cdsval = this.cdsid.concat(this.firstNameval);
           
          });
          
         
          const combinedVal: Observable<any> = of(this.cdsval)
            .pipe(
              distinct()
            );

          return combinedVal;
        } else {
          return of(fdsDataFromSql[0].fdsContact);
        }
      }),

      catchError((error) => {
        this._isError = true;
        return EMPTY;
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this._isLoading = false;
        this._isError = false;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please clean up this code a little (remove comments etc.) so that it's clearer to read and easier to figure out what's the problem?

Comment: cleaned up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to an observable you tell Angular to never wait for the result and execute the following statement as subscribe() is a synchronous function.
To resolve this you need to put the following statement inside the subscription function else you can use async functions (Example: `const result = await this.http.get("/blabla").toPromise();`) then the script will never execute the next statement until he gets the result.